# subsribe to two integer type msgs with one call back function

Tags: ros, subscribe, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to subscribe to two integer types .But lot of errors are showing .Please help me to correct the code
code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <std_msgs/Int8.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>

using namespace std_msgs;
```

using namespace message_filters;

void callback(const Int8ConstPtr& angle,const Int8ConstPtr& range_data)
{

```
}
   int main( int argc, char** argv )
   {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "basic_shapes");
     ros::NodeHandle n;
     ros::Rate r(1);
 message_filters::Subscriber<Int8> sub1(n,"angle", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber<Int8> sub2(n,"range_data", 1);
TimeSynchronizer<Int8,Int8> sync(sub1,sub2,10);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback,_1, _2));
   
ros::spin();
return 0;

}
```

error msgs:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h: In instantiation of ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::add(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0; M0 = std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >; M1 = std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters::NullType; M4 = message_filters::NullType; M5 = message_filters::NullType; M6 = message_filters::NullType; M7 = message_filters::NullType; M8 = message_filters::NullType; typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >]’:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:358:5:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::cb(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>; typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:290:138:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&, F8&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F8 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:282:52:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:275:48:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:268:44:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:261:40:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:36:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:247:32:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:240:28:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/time_synchronizer.h:120:24:   required from ‘message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::TimeSynchronizer(F0&, F1&, uint32_t) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; M0 = std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >; M1 = std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters::NullType; M4 = message_filters::NullType; M5 = message_filters::NullType; M6 = message_filters::NullType; M7 = message_filters::NullType; M8 = message_filters::NullType; uint32_t = unsigned int]’
/home/anand/catkin_ws/src/using_markers/src/basic_shapes.cpp:40:46:   required from here
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h:127:101: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, void>’
Tuple& t = tuples_[mt::TimeStamp<typename mpl::at_c<Messages, i>::type>::value(*evt.getMessage())];
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h: In instantiation of ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::add(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 1; M0 = std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >; M1 = std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters::NullType; M4 = message_filters::NullType; M5 = message_filters::NullType; M6 = message_filters::NullType; M7 = message_filters::NullType; M8 = message_filters::NullType; typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >]’:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:358:5:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::cb(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 1; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>; typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:291:138:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&, F8&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F8 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:282:52:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:275:48:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:268:44:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:261:40:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:36:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:247:32:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:240:28:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer::connectInput(F0&, F1&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/time_synchronizer.h:120:24:   required from ‘message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::TimeSynchronizer(F0&, F1&, uint32_t) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void > >; M0 = std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >; M1 = std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters::NullType; M4 = message_filters::NullType; M5 = message_filters::NullType; M6 = message_filters::NullType; M7 = message_filters::NullType; M8 = message_filters::NullType; uint32_t = unsigned int]’
/home/anand/catkin_ws/src/using_markers/src/basic_shapes.cpp:40:46:   required from here
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h:127:101: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::Int8_std::allocator<void >, void>’
make[2]: *** [using_markers/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/src/basic_shapes.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [using_markers/CMakeFiles/basic_shapes.dir/all] Error 2

But the same code work for sensor_msg type. why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248891/subsribe-to-two-integer-type-msgs-with-one-call-back-function/) by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-11-27

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"The TimeSynchronizer filter synchronizes incoming channels by the timestamps contained in their headers,"

No header -> No TimeSynchronizer

And please:

1. invest some seconds to check your
   spelling
2. don't post irrelevant
   code (commented includes??)
3. format code as such (use to
   101010-Button)
4. "But lot of errors
   are showing" The is no ROS-interface
   to chrystal balls yet, so please
   post the error messages.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on 2016-11-27**:
i edited my post and put the error messages in the post,Now can you please help me to resolve this problem.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-11-27**:
I already answered the question. and @gvdhoorn also told you in your first thread "If both messages have headers"... And you broke the code formatting and still have typos in the question.

**Comment by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on 2016-11-27**:
Both message have the header #include <std_msgs/Int8.h>.I didn't understand what you are saying?Can you clarify

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-11-27**:
Please fix your question (formatting, typos)

**Comment by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on 2016-11-27**:
I already corrected my question

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-11-27**:
neither is the code formatted correctly nor have you removed the typos. I'm sorry to be a bit pedantic, but you want some help here and some effort on your side should be visible.